# Calculate the maximum value for a group of pixels

Tags: r, max, aggregate, pixel, raster

I have a raster image with a resolution of 1,1.

I want to decrease the resolution to 4,4 but still have the maximum value of the pixel that makes up the new 4,4 pixel.

I can reduce the resolution by using:

```
chm4 <- aggregate(chm, 4)
```

However, this gives you the average maximum from each pixel that makes up this new pixel.

I tried to convert the raster to a matrix so it takes the form of:

```
     [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]...
[1,]  63    34   45   76   21   54   35   45
[2,]  77    54   43   34   12   23   73   26
[3,]  56    73   26   27   81   29   34   52
[4,]  31    48   61   35   76   38   17   87
[5,]  16    24   71   45   58   60   14   35
[6,]  28    64   27   63   18   62   43   27
[7,]  27    48   76   27   54   61   52   44
[8,]  56    37   53   62   37   47   52   38 
...
```

Is there a way to calculate the max of all values within, for example, rows 1 to 4 and columns 1 to 4?

This would also need to be applied across the whole matrix which has 1000's of rows and columns back into a matrix form to look like:

```
    [,1][,2]...
[1,] 77  87
[2,] 76  62
...
```

Comment: I haven't used this but take a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lambda.tools/lambda.tools.pdf

Comment: umm...how about using `aggregate(chm, fact = c(2,2), fun = max)`?

Comment: This still returns the average max rather than the max max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another possibility, using a for-loop on a sample matrix (mat):

```
x <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE)
mat <- matrix(x, nrow = 10)
mat2 <- matrix(nrow = nrow(mat)/4, ncol = ncol(mat)/4)

for(i in 1:dim(mat2)[1]) {
  for(j in 1:dim(mat2)[2]) {
    row <- 4 * (i - 1) + 1
    col <- 4 * (j - 1) + 1
    mat2[i,j] <- max(mat[row:(row + 3), col:(col + 3)])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the matrix into an array and use `apply`. If your data is not truly massive, this should be fast enough for most applications.

```
#the example data
M <- structure(c(63L, 77L, 56L, 31L, 16L, 28L, 27L, 56L, 34L, 54L, 
                 73L, 48L, 24L, 64L, 48L, 37L, 45L, 43L, 26L, 61L, 71L, 27L, 76L, 
                 53L, 76L, 34L, 27L, 35L, 45L, 63L, 27L, 62L, 21L, 12L, 81L, 76L, 
                 58L, 18L, 54L, 37L, 54L, 23L, 29L, 38L, 60L, 62L, 61L, 47L, 35L, 
                 73L, 34L, 17L, 14L, 43L, 52L, 52L, 45L, 26L, 52L, 87L, 35L, 27L, 
                 44L, 38L), .Dim = c(8L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))

#create an array
A <- M
dim(A) <- c(2, nrow(M) / 2, 2, ncol(M) / 2)

#loop over the appropriate margins    
apply(A, c(2, 4), max)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   77   76   54   73
#[2,]   73   61   81   87
#[3,]   64   71   62   43
#[4,]   56   76   61   52
```

If this is too slow, it would be easy to write an Rcpp function for this specific task. You'd simply need a double loop.